# Bind margin inside datatemplate is not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

Im trying to bind my usercontrols (that have a move on mouse left btn logic inside its code behind) margin inside a datatemplate of an itemscontrol. However when being bound inside the datatemplate it doesnt update itself when a move on the grid behind it (which itself is a usercontrol aswell and has a move on mouse middle button logic inside its code behind).

The code behind of those is: (where in the grid it reacts to middle mouse)

```
private void Control_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
            isDragging = true;
            var draggableControl = sender as UserControl;
            lasttransform = new Point(0, 0);
            clickPosition = e.GetPosition(this.Parent as UIElement);
            draggableControl.CaptureMouse();
    }

    private void Control_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging == true)
        {
            isDragging = false;
            var draggable = sender as UserControl;
            draggable.ReleaseMouseCapture();



            completetransform = Point.Add(completetransform,new Vector( lasttransform.X, lasttransform.Y));
            lasttransform = new Point(0, 0);
        }
    }

    private void Control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var draggableControl = sender as UserControl;

        if (isDragging && draggableControl != null && draggableControl.GetType() == typeof(BaseNode))
        {
            Point currentPosition = e.GetPosition(this.Parent as UIElement);
            currentPosition = new Point(currentPosition.X, currentPosition.Y);


            var transform = draggableControl.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
            if (transform == null)
            {
                transform = new TranslateTransform();
                draggableControl.RenderTransform = transform;
            }

            transform.X = completetransform.X + (currentPosition.X - clickPosition.X);
            transform.Y = completetransform.Y + (currentPosition.Y - clickPosition.Y);

            lasttransform = new Point((currentPosition.X - clickPosition.X), (currentPosition.Y - clickPosition.Y));
        }
    }
}
```

When i now want to show my controls in some window like:

```
<Grid>
    <my:EventGrid x:Name="XDisplayedEventGrid" Margin="-20" DataContext="{Binding DisplayedEventGrid}"/>
    <Grid Background="Red" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{Binding DisplayedEventGrid.ActualTransform, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=PointToMarginConverter}}"/>

    <my:BaseNode HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="{Binding DisplayedEventGrid.ActualTransform, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=PointToMarginConverter}}"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayedNodes}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <my:BaseNode HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="{Binding  ElementName=XDisplayedEventGrid, Path=ActualTransform, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=PointToMarginConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Where 'my:EventGrid 'is the movable grid, 'my:BaseNode' is a control to test everything and DataTemplate> my:BaseNode .../> /DataTemplate> is the actual displaying control for these usercontrols.

What should happen:

1) When you move the grid behind the visual brush makes it look like you can scroll unlimitedly.

2) The 'Grid Background="Red"' stays at its place on the eventgrid.

3) The Margin is bound to the eventgrid's moved coordinates which is translated to a margin by a converter, so for the user it looks like the controls stay on place on the grid and get moved out of view if the user looks at another portion of the grid.

4) When a node is moved its RenderTransform is set so it can be placed by and bound to a margin while being able to reposition it locally with the RenderTransform.

My Problem now is, that when the test-node has no DataContext bound it has the behavior of the grid and moves accordingly, but if it has one set it acts like the node inside the datatemplate and stays at 0,0 of the window.

The Datacontext of the node is an empty class deriving of a standard implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged.

When not having a datacontext bound inside the datatemplate it still has the same wrong behavior.

Where is my error and
are there any better controls to store externally marged usercontrols?

Thanks

ShinuSha